# Two-way binding not updating view model

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to use two-way binding in an Ext JS 6.0.2 component. However, it's not working how I would expect it to, or at all, as far as I can tell. I've created a minimal example:

```
Ext.define('MyComponentController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.mycomponent'
});

Ext.define('MyComponentModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.mycomponent'
});

Ext.define('MyComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'mycomponent',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'mycomponent'
    },
    controller: 'mycomponent',

    config: {
        thing: 'a defualt value'
    },
    bind: {
        thing: '{thing}'
    },
    twoWayBindable: 'thing'
});

var myComponent = Ext.create('MyComponent', {
    thing: 'a new value'
});

// Use setTimeout to give bindings time to update.
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(myComponent.getViewModel().get('thing'));
}, 1000);
```

I also have a Sencha fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1efk

What I would expect from running this code is to see `a new value` logged to the console. Instead, I get `null`. The value that is being set on my view is not being published to my view model, even though I have `bind` and `twoWayBindable` set. Have I misunderstood how to use two-way binding?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g3e)

It's a fork of your example. I've added a few things:

- `Ext.application` with a `launch` method and placed the creation of `myComponent` here.
- rendered `myComponent` to `Ext.getBody()`.
- an update method for the `thing` config, which logs its value when changed.
- a [ViewModel binding](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-bind), which logs its value when changed.

<s>Ext does not set up bindings until the viewmodel is initialized. This does not happen until the view itself is initialized. That's why why it's necessary to render it.</s> As  Mitchell Simoens correctly pointed out, instantiating a view will initialize it and its viewmodel, even when it isn't rendered. In my example, however, the viewmodel bind callback is only executed when i'm actually rendering the view.

Also, keep in mind that bindings are scheduled and do not fire instantly.

In case you haven't seen it, here's [Ext JS's two-way binding example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#binding-two-way).

I hope this clarifies things!

Comment: "Ext does not set up bindings until the viewmodel is initialized. This does not happen until the view itself is initialized." is a bit misleading. You can instantiate (which will call initComponent which may mean the view is initialized) but not render it and the viewmodel is also initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After fiddling (pun intended) with the example i saw when you mean. I've corrected my answer, which hopefully is accurate now :)

Answer (score -2):

replace your `console.log` line with this:

```
console.log(myComponent.getThing());
```

Comment: This will work but it's missing the point. I'm trying to update the value of thing in the view model. You're telling me to get it from the view instead, which won't work in the real use case for this.